# How was this visualization created? What tools and technologies can I use to create such dynamic visualizations?

Tags: frontend, visualization

[https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/OpenHash.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/OpenHash.html)

I am new to frontend development and only know a couple of technologies like HTML, CSS and bootstrap. I am curious to know what technology was used to create this visualization?

Answer (score 0):

The best data visualization tools include Google Charts, Tableau, Grafana, Chartist. js, FusionCharts, Datawrapper, Infogram, ChartBlocks, and D3

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those tools was used to create the visualisation the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

That is a custom visualisation by David Galles that he built on top of [jQuery (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.2](http://jquery.com/) and jQuery UI 1.8.11). I do not see anything else linked in the code. Aside from jQuery it's plain HTML, CSS, and Javascript.